# SD Card file changes don't trigger apps to update

Tags: filesystem, git

I've recently moved my git repo to an always plugged in SD card, formatted to OS X Extended I've noticed with both SourceTree and WebStorm don't pick up on file changes anymore. Gets really annoying when you reset files from the command line, make some changes and then when you go to save that file WebStorm complains that the file has changed.

Edit:

New found info, this actually appears to be an issue with symbolic links. When I moved my projects to the new SD card, I made a symbolic link in my home directory to the SD card, because I have some scripts that are setup to expect that. This also came with the convenience that WebStorm's project bookmarks would just work too. When I deleted the old bookmark and made a new one to the SD card location everything's working as expected.

So new question is, is this just a limitation of symbolic links in OS X, or is there something I can do to combat this.